# How can I select out parameters in a MySQL procedure as table columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Environment: MySQL 5.1, Linux

I have a stored procedure that computes several values from a single input value. The values are returned as OUT parameters. I would like to call this procedure for every row set and have the values appear as columns in the result set. The values have a complex relationship such that distinct *functions* for each value is not easily constructed.

The question: How can I get OUT parameters to show up as columns in a table?

Here's what I have so far:

```
DELIMITER $_$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS in_out;
CREATE PROCEDURE in_out (
       IN s TEXT, 
       OUT op TEXT, 
       OUT opn INT,
       OUT opd TEXT,
       OUT len INT
       )
BEGIN
        SET op = 'del';
        SET opn = 1;
        SET opd = substr(s,4);
        SET len = LENGTH(SUBSTR(s,4));
END
$_$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then:

```
mysql> call in_out('delACT',@op,@opn,@opd,@len);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @op,@opn,@opd,@len;
+------+------+------+------+
| @op  | @opn | @opd | @len |
+------+------+------+------+
| snv  |    1 | ACT  |    3 |
+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So far so good, but I can't figure out how to call this procedure for every row and return the results in the result set.  I want is something like this:

```
dream> select mycol,in_out(mycol) from mytable
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| mycol   | @op  | @opn | @opd | @len |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| delACT  | del  |    1 | ACT  |    3 |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want something like a `CROSS APPLY` from SQL Server, but I do not know if MySQL has an equivalent.

Comment: Actually, what I really want is PostgreSQL table functions, but that's where I start to get weepy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a trick question: one can't create table relations out of function/procedure results in MySQL.  I ended up refactoring into separate functions (as suggested by Michał).  I had been hoping for a MySQL equivalent to PostgreSQL's table functions (http://goo.gl/77QVE).

Answer (score 1):

You confuse the stored procedures and stored functions:

- stored function will be return a value, the results can be used in
  expressions (like COS() and other mysql built-in functions).
- stored procedure need use CALL , is an independent operation, can not
  be    used in expressions.

If you want to "select mycol,in_out(mycol) from mytable",you must:

```
CREATE FUNCTION in_out( ...
```

Comment: I understand the distinction and did not confuse them, but I should have stated that more clearly. (The sentence about not being able to construct distinct functions was intended to motivate why functions are awkward for this particular use.)

Comment: I was hoping for a MySQL equivalent of PostgreSQL's table functions. Roughly speaking, these are functions that return a relation (perhaps with just one row) that act just like tables. Example: http://pastebin.com/DZVJAvD6. NOTE: This comment is only to clarify the kind of solution I was after.  To all who follow, this thread is not about MySQL v. PostgreSQL; please comment on the original question only.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to prepare data in stored procedure for each possible value in:

```sql
select distinct mycol
from mytable
where <... condition that you would use anyway in final result ...>
```

where `mycol` is your parameter for stored procedure save it to temporary table and than join to this values.

```sql
-- way the temp table may look in your sp
create temporary table tmptable (
    mycol text
    op text, 
    opn int,
    opd text,
    len int
)
```

after that use join:

```sql
select m.mycol, t.op, t.opn, t.opd, t.len
from mytable m
join tmptable t on m.mycol = t.mycol
where <... condition that you would use anyway in final result ...>
```

Bit different question, are you absolutely sure that there is no different way to process your final result than using a stored procedure?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that I *can* refactor as four distinct functions, but they'll almost certainly be less efficient, even if I consolidate repeated code with DETERMINISTIC functions. With MySQL, it appears that this is the only route.

Comment: Stored function for each "column" will be the easiest way to do it and probably slowest, there is a chance that stored procedure that fills temp table might be faster. If you are going to process only a few rows at a time go the simplest approach - stored functions.